# Create windows phone app from html/php/sql

Tags: windows-phone-8, localhost, mobile-application

I have a mobile website that I have made, and I want to make it into an app for my windows phone. It uses a mysql database that must be built into the app as this needs to be available offline. What services or software out there exists to make this possible?

Failing the above, is there a way to run a localhost (eg xampp or easyphp) on a windows phone?

Answer (score 0):

[Local database for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

You will need to transfer your mysql database schema to an SQLCompact 3.5 database which is the only supported database environment for the windows phone platform.

Answer (score -1):

The better way for you is to build app ([javascript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh975345.aspx) or even c#) for a Windows Phone with SQLite database as a backend. There is no way to launch anything at localhost and background agents is not suitable for your tasks. MySql is also not supported.